# What are some examples of weak ω-categories?

Tags: higher-category-theory, big-list, ct.category-theory

As is usual, let's say an (*n*, *k*)-category is something with
objects, morphisms, 2-morphisms, ..., *n*-morphisms, such that all
*j*-morphisms for *j* > *k* are invertible, everything meant in the
weak sense. We can also take *n* = ∞ or *n* = *k* = ∞. In this
terminology the weak ω-categories in the title question are
(∞,∞)-categories.

I think the only examples I know of weak ω-categories that are not (∞,
*k*)-categories for some finite *k* are the ∞-category of all
∞-categories and the ∞-category `Cob` whose *n*-morphisms are
*n*-dimensional manifolds (with corners) thought of as cobordisms
between some specified (*n*-1)-dimensional manifolds (with corners).
(I saw Dominic Verity give a very nice talk about his construction of
a PL-version of this as a weak complicial set.) Of course, `Cob` has
many variants, and we could also look at constructions such as functor
categories, coproducts, products, etc., starting from these.

I'd be very interested in hearing about other examples of
(∞,∞)-categories, even if they haven't really been constructed in the
literature yet. Specially examples like `Cob` which are not internal to
the theory of (∞,∞)-categories.

EDIT: I think that Sam Gunningham is right and I forgot (again) that the difference between having duals and having inverses is supposed to fall of the edge of the world when you go all the way out to ∞, so that `Cob` is an ∞-groupoid (specifically, it should be the well-known space classifying whatever kind of cobordism you used to build `Cob`). This means that I actually don't know any examples of genuinely (∞,∞)-categories that come from outside higher category theory.

EDIT 2: I somehow missed [this earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73772/concrete-example-of-infty-categories). Maybe my question should be closed as a duplicate.

EDIT 3: Jeremy Hahn has convinced me that Sam's comment is true or false depending on how you define the equivalences of (∞,∞)-categories, and that it is not clear whether you really want every (∞,∞)-category with all adjoints to be an ∞-groupoid.

Comment: I thought the $(\infty, \infty)$-category of bordisms should in fact be an $(\infty, 0)$-category. Naively, wouldn't being ``$\infty$-dualizable'' mean that every morphism is invertible? 

Comment: Yes, I think that's right @SamGunningham. I've added a remark about this to the question.

Comment: Omar it is not clear what the homotopy theory of (infinity,infinity)-categories should be. Let J denote the nerve of the contractible groupoid with 2 objects. Then inverting J and all of its suspensions yields one homotopy theory. There is a second, different homotopy theory in which a category with all adjoints is contractible. If one looks only at (infinity,n)-categories these two homotopy theories are the same, but I believe they are not the same at (infinity,infinity). I think that the category of bordisms is only contractible in the second sense

Comment: Did you mean $\infty$-groupoid instead of contractible, @JeremyHahn? I mean an ordinary groupoid has all adjoints, right? I certainly don't want it to be contractible as an $(\infty,\infty)$-category. (Or do I?) If this second homotopy theory of $(\infty,\infty)$-categories makes either (1) a all homotopy types contractible, or (2) homotopy inverses not count as adjoints, it doesn't sound like such a great idea.

Comment: This might be too naïve, but E_n-algebras can be organized into an (∞,n+1)-category, so perhaps E_∞-algebras can be organized into an (∞,∞)-category?

Comment: I meant infinity groupoid.  Homotopy inverses should always count as adjoints, but only in the second theory is there a kind of converse for towers of adjoints going all the way up to infinity.

Comment: I think the cobordism categories are much more interesting in the first homotopy theory, the advantage of the second being that it has a nice "coinductive" definition ala the model structure on strict omega categories.  Presumably strict omega categories have a second model structure that better represents the first theory.

Comment: I agree that your question looks like a duplicate, but I am hesitant to close it unilaterally.

Comment: An example I think of Dmitri Pavlov's comment: spaces are $E_\infty$ algebras in the category of spaces with correspondences, and the corresponding Morita $(\infty,\infty)$ category should have objects spaces, morphisms correspondences, 2-morphisms correspondences of correspondences, and so on all the way up. OTOH I think any space (or $E_\infty$ algebra) is $n$-dualizable for any $n$, so not sure how this agrees with Sam's comment. 

Comment: @Jeremy Hahn: Can you describe what an invertible morphism in a (weak) $\omega$-category would look like in the first homotopy theory you consider?

Comment: @Ricardo I can try... it's hard without pictures.  Basically, in the first homotopy theory a morphism is invertible if it is part of a tower of adjoints that terminates at a higher identity morphism.  This is in contrast to the second theory where a morphism is invertible simply if it is part of a tower of adjoints, with no restriction that the tower eventually degenerate into higher identity morphisms.

Comment: @Jeremy: Thank you very much for the explanation. I just want to make sure I understand correctly what you mean by "higher identity morphism". Would that be a degenerate simplex (or globule, etc) in some multi-simplicial or globular approach? Or maybe it is a thin simplex in a complicial approach? Is that correct? Is there a better way to think about it?

Comment: Yes it seems you have the idea.  The higher identity morphisms should indeed be degenerate multi-simplices or globules.  Even in the case of complicial sets the higher identity morphisms should be characterized by degeneracy conditions rather than thinness.

Comment: @Jeremy: Thank you for the clarification.